# Не работает PushButton в PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Начал свое освоение pyQT5 сделал графический интерфейс с помощью QT Designer, но кнопки не реагируют на нажатие.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'calc.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(False)
        MainWindow.resize(436, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -11, 501, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120, 122, 255);\n"
                                 "color: rgb(255, 74, 222);")
        self.label.setIndent(2)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.btn4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 140, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn4.setFont(font)
        self.btn4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn4.setObjectName("btn4")
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn.setFont(font)
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                               "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                               "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                               "")
        self.btn.setObjectName("btn")
        self.btn6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 140, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn6.setFont(font)
        self.btn6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn6.setObjectName("btn6")
        self.btn7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 70, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn7.setFont(font)
        self.btn7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn7.setObjectName("btn7")
        self.btn0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 280, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn0.setFont(font)
        self.btn0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn0.setObjectName("btn0")
        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 210, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn1.setFont(font)
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn1.setObjectName("btn1")
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 210, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn2.setFont(font)
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn2.setObjectName("btn2")
        self.btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 210, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn3.setFont(font)
        self.btn3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn3.setObjectName("btn3")
        self.btn8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 70, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn8.setFont(font)
        self.btn8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn8.setObjectName("btn8")
        self.btn9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 70, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn9.setFont(font)
        self.btn9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                "")
        self.btn9.setObjectName("btn9")
        self.btn_del = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_del.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 70, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn_del.setFont(font)
        self.btn_del.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                   "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                   "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                   "")
        self.btn_del.setObjectName("btn_del")
        self.btn_multiply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_multiply.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 140, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn_multiply.setFont(font)
        self.btn_multiply.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                        "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                        "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                        "")
        self.btn_multiply.setObjectName("btn_multiply")
        self.btn_minus = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_minus.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 210, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn_minus.setFont(font)
        self.btn_minus.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                     "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                     "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                     "")
        self.btn_minus.setObjectName("btn_minus")
        self.btn_sum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_sum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 280, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn_sum.setFont(font)
        self.btn_sum.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                   "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                   "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                   "")
        self.btn_sum.setObjectName("btn_sum")
        self.btn_float = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_float.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 280, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn_float.setFont(font)
        self.btn_float.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                     "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                     "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                     "")
        self.btn_float.setObjectName("btn_float")
        self.btn_equal = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_equal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 280, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("System")
        self.btn_equal.setFont(font)
        self.btn_equal.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
                                     "color: rgb(0, 0, 255);\n"
                                     "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 127);\n"
                                     "")
        self.btn_equal.setObjectName("btn_equal")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 436, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.add_functions()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Калькулятор"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.btn4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.btn6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.btn7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.btn0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.btn2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.btn3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.btn8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.btn9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.btn_del.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        self.btn_multiply.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "x"))
        self.btn_minus.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.btn_sum.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.btn_float.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ","))
        self.btn_equal.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))

    def add_functions(self):
        self.btn0.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn0.text()))
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn1.text()))
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn2.text()))
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn3.text()))
        self.btn4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn4.text()))
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn.text()))
        self.btn6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn0.text()))
        self.btn7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn7.text()))
        self.btn8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn8.text()))
        self.btn9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn9.text()))
        self.btn_del.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_del.text()))
        self.btn_sum.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_sum.text()))
        self.btn_equal.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_equal.text()))
        self.btn_minus.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_minus.text()))
        self.btn_multiply.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.btn_multiply.text()))

    def write_number(self, number):
        print(number)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Есть подозрения, что не регистрирует метод add_functions, но для меня не очевидно - почему (Разместил в конце setupUi).
В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается проблема заключалась в MainWindow.setEnabled(False), я изменил на True и все заработало. Как я понимаю, ставит по умолчанию False, потому что окон может быть несколько.

Comment: Нет, по умолчанию это свойство имеет значение true. Читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop . Как вы добились того что у вас появилась стока `MainWindow.setEnabled(False)` - это большой вопрос к вам. Это первая ваша проблема, но не последняя, т.к. вы не читаете что вам пишут в самом начале `# ...  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.` Перевожу на русский - `НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.`